# appengine.applications.get permissions required for cloud task queues API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am hitting the REST API for cloud tasks queues via roughly:

```
import { cloudtasks_v2 } from "googleapis/build/src/apis/cloudtasks/v2";


const cloudTasksClient = new cloudtasks_v2.Cloudtasks({ auth: authClient });
cloudTasksClient.projects.locations.list({
  name: `projects/${projectId}`
});
```

and I am getting this error:

App Engine targets require "appengine.applications.get" IAM permission (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/access-control) and the API_CLOUD_PLATFORM scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform).

the REST API does not state that the permission is needed for that call

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/list

Is there any way to only get the queues that don't require app engine permissions, or to circumvent this error?
I do not want to give permissions to app engine

I tried on a project with app engine tasks and it works, but on a project with app engine tasks it throws an error and I can't determine a way to work around that.

Comment: The doc you linked to is talking about permissions to invoke the REST call whereas the error is saying - to access a url which is on a GAE App, you need certain permissions. These are 2 different things. You either give the permission or move the url (target endpoint) off a GAE App (if this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

give editor rights to
{}.iam.gserviceaccount.com in iam permissions